# Need an int variable to update with the push of a button and return output into a textview including £ symbol

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have the basic working ie, updating the textview by one after button click but I need to make it update with a £ symbol for example. One click = £1 Two clicks = £2.

```
 btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        //Setting up what happens when button btnClick is clicked, below code is executed
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String countValue=(txtCount.getText().toString());
            // Creating new variable (countValue) with the value of txtCount and converting to string
            int intCountValue=Integer.parseInt(countValue);
            intCountValue++;
            //Creating new integer variable (intCountValue) with number value parsed from string variable (countValue) plus 1
            txtCount.setText("£"+String.valueOf(intCountValue));
            //Updates the text in txtCount to the new string value of (intCountValue)

        }
    });
    btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String countValue=(txtCount.getText().toString());
            // Creating new variable (countValue) with the value of txtCount and converting to string
            int intCountValue=Integer.parseInt(countValue);
            //Creating new integer variable (intCountValue) with number value parsed from string variable (countValue) plus 1
            txtCount.setText("£"+String.valueOf(intCountValue));
            //Updates the text in txtCount to the new string value of (intCountValue)
            txtCount.setText("£"+String.valueOf(0));
```

Comment: ... and your question is?

Comment: How do I implement the £ symbol into my output? When i try i get error telling me £0 is an invalid integer

Comment: Append the symbol to your text like `setText("£"+String.valueOf(intCountValue))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
txtCount.setText("£"+String.valueOf(intCountValue));
```

Comment: Gets past my splash screen the crashes, Pasted your code in and it was highlighted yellow with "Do not concatenate text displayed with setText, use resource string with placeholders.

Comment: Make a resoure string with "$". Then get it with R.string.nameOfDollarString
But does it work despite of that?

Answer (score 0):

Append the symbol to your text like 
setText("£"+String.valueOf(intCountValue))

```
btnClick2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            //Setting up what happens when button btnClick is clicked, below code is executed
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String countValue = txtCount.getText().toString().replace("£","");
                // Creating new variable (countValue) with the value of txtCount and converting to string
                int intCountValue = Integer.parseInt(countValue);
                intCountValue++;
                //Creating new integer variable (intCountValue) with number value parsed from string variable (countValue) plus 1
                txtCount.setText("£"+String.valueOf(intCountValue));
                //Updates the text in txtCount to the new string value of (intCountValue)
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your count value shall be an attribute and use a formatter to display it

```
intCountValue++;
txtCount.setText(String.format("£%d", intCountValue));
```

In fact, this attribute shall be part of your model and the text label should listen its change to display it. Using properties of javafx it could be :

```
txtCount.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("£%d", model.countProperty());
```

(where textCount is a Label)

Comment: Worked perfectly life saver thank you very much could i be really cheeky and ask if you could explain what is going on in your code. Im very new to this and really want to understand it! thank you again

Comment: Bindings is simply a way to implement the pattern observer easily as javafx property do it for you. In fact, every time countProperty value change, textCount is computed applying the format you provide.